# How to get percentage of data results in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to get a percentage of one column in my result data.
In the end I want to know how a percentage(or count) of valide and invalide.

```
select 
study_date_dossier_pret
,study_id
,rapport_signe_date
,DATEDIFF(minute,[rapport_signe_date],[study_date_dossier_pret]) as TIME
, case 
   when DATEDIFF(minute,[rapport_signe_date],[study_date_dossier_pret]) <=0 then 'invalide'
else 'valide'
end Etat
from PremierTrimestre
    ,rapportPremierTrimestre

WHERE   PremierTrimestre.study_uid=rapportPremierTrimestre.rapport_study_id
```

Comment: How would you calculate the percentage if you just had a   paper and a pencil?

Comment: What you mean Tim !!

Answer (score 0):

You can get each on of the numbers like these:

```
SELECT SUM(t.invalid) AS nr_of_invalid, SUM(t.valid) AS nr_of_valid
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ...
        ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(minute, [rapport_signe_date], [study_date_dossier_pret]) <= 0 
            THEN 1  
            ELSE 0
        END AS invalid
        ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(minute, [rapport_signe_date], [study_date_dossier_pret]) <= 0 
            THEN 0  
            ELSE 1
        END AS valid
    FROM PremierTrimestre, rapportPremierTrimestre
    WHERE PremierTrimestre.study_uid = rapportPremierTrimestre.rapport_study_id
) t
```

Now you need to do the math, and put there the columns you want

Comment: not works, invalid and valid are not columns of table

Comment: Nobody said they were.. they are counters that I set based on your conditions.

Comment: Show me the final query, you can't just paste what I wrote

Comment: @gilas - Sample data and expected output will avoid these confusions

Comment: Well if you paste my query without the `...,` you have to get something at least

Comment: aha, you're right Miguel.thanks,but percentage :(( i couldn't find

Comment: That is about `FORMAT`, try `FORMAT(<the number you want to format>, "Percent")`

Answer (score 0):

This is my end result:

study_id|study_date_dossier_pret|rapport_signe_date|TIME|Etat

2014-01-12 13:12:28.000 349344  2014-01-12 13:21:29.000 -9  invalide 
2014-01-12 13:09:38.000 349346  2014-01-12 12:51:32.000 18   valide
2014-01-12 13:55:05.000 349373  2014-01-12 13:53:07.000 2    valide
2014-01-12 14:04:38.000 349374  2014-01-12 14:02:07.000 2    valide
......

i want from this results, get how many there are valide rows and invalide rows by  percentage

for exemple: 
valide 82% 
invalide 18%

Comment: I don't want to write the code for you... The query i gave you must give you the number of valid and invalid, after that you just need to do valid/(valid+invalid). Do you know what a `GROUP BY` is?